# Android showcase focus tablayout

Tags: android, showcaseview

I'm using [FancyShowCaseView](https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5440) library. When focusing on a button it work fine, but when focusing on TabLayout or MenuItem of Android SlidingTabs it don't work.

I'm tring to focus on TabLayout or MenuItem's of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listen i have the same problem and add this:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
   new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
      // Layout has happened here.
      // Don't forget to remove your listener when you are done with it.
      view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
  }
});
```

to my code and work fine.